# Monotouch.Dialog: Adding Sections without "flying in" annimation

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

After a Root Element is made and displayed, I sometimes need to add a new section:

```
this.Root.Add(MyNewPopulatedsection);
```

The problem is that the new Section 'flys in' from the right in an animation.

How do I add a section, but not have it animate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is very inefficient, but can you just create new Root element with old and new sections and then reassign your DialogViewController.Root to it.